My Telegram bot is not responding—TypeError in bot.polling() argument of type 'function' is not iterable
I am developing a Telegram bot using the telebot library, but I ran into a problem due to which the bot does not respond to some commands, but fills in others. Instead, I get the following error:
2024-10-26 12:07:46,918 (init.py:7144 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "message_handler: Commands filter should be list of strings (commands), unknown type supplied to the 'commands' filter list. Not able to. return message.content_type == 'text' and util.extract_command(message.text) in filter_value TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
use the supplied type."
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
     
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    buttons = [
        ' Баланс',
        ' Торговля',
        ' Курсы',
        ' Мои ордера',
        ' Пополнить',
        ' Вывести',
        '⚙️ Настройки',
        '❓ Помощь'
    ]
    markup.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(button) for button in buttons])
    
    bot.reply_to(message, 
                 "Добро пожаловать", 
                 reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == ' Баланс')
def show_balance(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    
    response = " Ваш баланс: 20"
    
    bot.reply_to(message, response)

the show_balance function runs without problems

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == '❓ Помощь')
def show_help(message):
    
    help_text = "0"
    bot.reply_to(message, help_text)

the show_help function causes an error without problems
    

Added error handling and logging to diagnose the problem, but it didn't do anything.
Error:

2024-10-26 12:07:46,918 (init.py:7144 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "message_handler: Commands filter should be list of strings (commands), unknown type supplied to the 'commands' filter list. Not able to use the supplied type
return message.content_type == 'text' and util.extract_command(message.text) in filter_value
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable.

change

I found a pattern if I drag a function closer to def send_welcome(message): then the function works and the other does not

